# Update the variable value after asynchronous http call

Tags: node.js, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-functions

I have a *firebase function* called `getRequest` which contains simple http calls using *request* npm package and a variable named `result` which will **should** contain the body response from the http call after request completed.
However, the `request` output is a `"this should be replaced"` string, because the http call runs asynchronously.
How do you get the `result` variable to contain the body response from the http call?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const request = require('request');

exports.getRequest = functions.https.onRequest(() => {
    let result = "this should be replaced";
    request('http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/est/now', function(error,response,body){
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
            result = body;
    });
    console.log(result);
});
```

I've tried to use *callback* but I'm confused to put the parameter, because actually this is also inside the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request` supports callback interfaces natively **but does not return a promise**. You **must** wait the asynchronous call to the external API is finished before sending back the response, and for this you should use a Promise which will resolves when the call to the API returns.

You can use the [`request-promise`](https://github.com/request/request-promise) library and the `rp()` method which "returns a regular Promises/A+ compliant promise" and then, adapt your code as follows:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const rp = require('request-promise');

exports.getRequest = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    let result = "this should be replaced";

    var options = {
        uri: 'http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/est/now',
        json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
    };

    rp(options)
        .then(parsedBody => {
            result = parsedBody.currentDateTime;
            console.log(result);
            res.send( {result} );
        })
        .catch(err => {
            // API call failed...
            res.status(500).send({'Error': err});
        });
});
```

---

I would suggest you watch the official Video Series (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/) which explains the key point about returning Promises and also how to handle errors in an HTTP Cloud Function.

---

Two extra points to note:

#### `onRequest()` arguments

You need to pass two arguments to the `onRequest()` function: the `Request and the`Response` objects, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?authuser=0#trigger_a_function_with_an_http_request

```
exports.date = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // ...
});
```

#### Pricing plan

You need to be on the "Flame" or "Blaze" pricing plan.

As a matter of fact, the free "Spark" plan "allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services". See https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ (hover your mouse on the question mark situated after the "Cloud Functions" title)

Since the worldclock API is not a Google-owned service, you need to switch to the "Flame" or "Blaze" plan.

Answer (score 2):

the callback calls asynchronous, so `console.log(result)` call before the callback run.
if you want to print the `result` variable with content from the requet you need to print it from the callback

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const request = require('request');

exports.getRequest = functions.https.onRequest(() => {
    let result = "this should be replaced";
    request('http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/est/now', function(error,response,body){
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
            result = body;
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

however, I recommend [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise) and use async/await syntax

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const request = require('request-promise');

exports.getRequest = functions.https.onRequest(async () => {
    let result = "this should be replaced";
    result = await request('http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/est/now');
    console.log(result);
});
```